# What is the fastest way to update just the data of a Javascript Plotly chart?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, plotly

I read here that for updating just the data property of a Plotly chart it is best to use the restyle method:

https://community.plot.ly/t/what-is-the-most-performant-way-to-update-a-graph-with-new-data/639

I have tried to implement this solution but found it to actually be slower than simply reinitializing the chart each time I need to update the data. This seems counter-intuitive because I would think there is some overhead in creating the chart object as well as setting all the layout/format properties. This makes me think I'm implementing the suggestion in an incorrect way.

Below are the two functions I am using to reset the data of my chart. The first function is the one I call when the page is first loaded and I need to initialize the chart. Each subsequent data set change results in the second function getting called. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Chart initialization function:

```
        function buildChart(tag)
        {
            var trace1 = {
                x: x,
                y: y1,
                name: 'X',
                type: 'bar',                 
                marker: {
                    color: 'blue'
                }
            };

            var trace2 = {
                x: x,
                y: y2,
                name: 'Y',
                type: 'bar',                 
                marker: {
                    color: 'red'
                }
            };

            var trace3 = {
                x: x,
                y: y3,
                name: 'Z',
                type: 'bar',                 
                marker: {
                    color: 'green'
                }
            };

            var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];
            var layout = {barmode: 'group', title: tag.split("-")[tag.split("-").length-1].replace("_", " ")};
            Plotly.newPlot(tag, data, layout);
        }
```

Update function:

```
        function updateChart(tag)
        {
            var trace1 = {
                x: [x],
                y: [y1]
            };

            var trace2 = {
                x: [x],
                y: [y2]
            };

            var trace3 = {
                x: [x],
                y: [y3]
            };

            Plotly.restyle(tag, trace1, 0);
            Plotly.restyle(tag, trace2, 1);
            Plotly.restyle(tag, trace3, 2);
        }
```

I have also tried the below for update function. Slightly faster than the first update function but still significantly slower than newPlot method:

```
    function updateChart(tag)
    {
        Plotly.restyle(tag, {y: [y1, y2, y3]}, [0,1,2]);
        Plotly.restyle(tag, {x: [x, x, x]}, [0,1,2]);
    }
```

Comment: How did you ascertain that the "performance gain was negligible".  How did you measure it and what were those measurements?

Comment: @MikeWise you inspired me to look at this more thoroughly. I admit I only "eyeballed" the differences because the performance is only as important as far as the user can notice, so the precision level didn't need to be that high. Exact measurements (as measured by js time difference), however, not only confirm my observation but show that the second method is actually two times slower (~2000 ms vs ~1000 ms)! This makes me think my implementation is wrong.